# Числа с плавающей точкой в глобальном сегменте

Tags: c, ассемблер

Почему значения чисел с плавающей точкой находятся глобальном сегменте?

***C:***

```
int t = 10;

void func()
{
    float x = 1.34f;
    int c =  1;

    t = 19;
    x = 1.5f;
    c = 98;
}
```

***Assembler:***

```
t:
        .long   10
func:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rbp-4], xmm0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR t[rip], 19
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rbp-4], xmm0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 98
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1068205343
.LC1:
        .long   1069547520
```

Comment: Метки ставьте правильные, `assembly != assembler`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Система команд процессора x86 не имеет команд с плавающей точкой, позволяющих встраивать непосредственные операнды прямо в код команды. Прочитать непосредственный операнд такая система команд может только из памяти. Поэтому эти операнды формируются компилятором в сегменте инициализированных данных, т.е. фактически являются безымянными инициализированными переменными.

Странный вопрос, вообще. Все константы с точки зрения базовой логики должны находиться в сегменте инициализированных данных. А где же им еще находиться? Это скорее исключение из правила, что *целочисленные* константы в некоторых системах команд можно встраивать непосредственно в код самой команды. Все остальное, естественно, идет в сегмент данных. Это вы и наблюдаете.

Вас, надеюсь, не удивляет, что литерал `"Hello World"` помещается компилятором в сегмент инициализированных данных? Тогда вас не должно удивлять и то, что константа `3.14` помещается компилятором туда же.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что есть инструкция `mov r32, imm32` (например `mov eax, 0x123` -- `B8 23 01 00 00`), но нету инструкции `mov xmm, imm32`.
Вместо неё есть инструкция `movss xmm, mem32` (тут  `movss xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]`).

Answer (score 2):

В функциях идёт их копирование в локальный сигмент. Компилятор превращает примерно в такой код:

```
int t = 10;
float lc0 = 1.34f; 
float lc1 = 1.5f;

void func()
{
    float x = lc0;
    int c =  1;

    t = 19;
    x = lc1;
    c = 98;
}
```

Comment: почему только `float`?

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой в xmm регистры копируются. Туда можно только по указателю на память копировать. Числа с плавающей точкой большие и, вероятно, архитектурного сложно запихивать в команду машинного кода значение. Целочисленные типы копируются в регистры общего назначения, а в них команды копирования поддерживают копирование по значению.